# Site errors in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Our site has taken a significant dip recently in daily visitors. It happened almost overnight in fact. I'v elooked in Webmaster tools and we have some 'Site Errors', listing DNS, Server Connectivity and Robots.txt Fetch:

. DNS - couldn't communicate with the DNS server

. Server connectivity - Request timed out or site is blocking Google

. Robots.txt Fetch - Crawl postponed bexcause robots.txt was
inaccessible

This is odd because I can reach the robots file with no issues at all. The line graph associated with each also shows no errors.  What's the problem here?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most probably your site error are 404 "Not found" messages. You need to take care about those errors. There will be cases where they are just wrong pages that it was bad typed or whatever, but some of those 404 you need to redirect to the correct page, using an 301 o 302 redirect.

About the messages of "DNS - couldn't communicate with the DNS server" and 0 error notificaction and 0 error on the graph below, it's just informative. But you need to take care that your site is online, and your DNS service is ok, with the "green tick"

[image: that's my webmaster tool tabs notifications]

Comment: Ok that's what I see - I assumed the hover messages were the errors. We've had a 50% drop in traffic - I've rectified the 1 URL error we had. Surely this wouldn't cause such an issue?

Comment: for sure not. An 50% drop in traffic seems to be other issue, something about the stability of your platform, maybe your server goes down, or similar. Maybe you lost the position of some keywords that you were indexed on Google.

consider to vote and accept the answer to close the question,